# Can Python scripts created with 64bit Python be run on same version but 32 bit Python?

Tags: python, 32bit-64bit

(And vice versa)

Or are there incompatibilities ?

PS: I will be using python 3.5.3 on 2 machines, but one on 64 bit and one on 32 bit. I will change writing/running scripts between the 2 machines often.

Comment: 64-bit Python will generally use about twice as much memory as 32-bit Python and, as a result, may run a little slower. There are no incompatibilities between the two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is an interpreted language, not a compiled one. That basically means that if you're referring to pure Python code, that is, code that does not rely on any native compile libraries, the answer is yes.

If not, then I guess it depends on a bunch of things.

Answer (score 2):

Anything really *created with 64bit Python* will probably not run under a 32bit version (for example, .pyc byte code files). Plain text scripts (.py files) created *with any text editor* is however compatible with both 32 and 64 bit Python interpreters.